# Do I have the full OS installed?

Tags: wubi

I installed Ubuntu using WUBI.exe last night which is running alongside my Windows 8.

When I boot up my laptop, I get given a choice between Windows or Ubuntu.

Am I running the full Ubuntu OS?

Every time I start my laptop into Ubuntu, my brightness is always on the lowest even though I set it to the brightest. My short-cut buttons on my laptop no longer work. For example, I use a 24" monitor to watch movies etc on, so using FN+F4 switches between displays easily. And using FN+F2/3 decreases and increases my brightness.

So far I love Ubuntu, but I'm very new at it. I do see myself replacing Windows 8 with Ubuntu in the near future.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you are running the full OS, but not in the most optimal way. None of the problems you have will have been caused by this though, so I would advise against replacing windows until you find a solution for them.